# Flutter manage animation controller from outside of class

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

this is my simple animation in class witch i use that

```
controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));

offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, -1.0)).animate(controller);
controller.forward();
```

in that i can only manage animation controller such as `forward`, `reverse` inside of class and i try to move this controller to outside of class like with another class as `NotificationBarController`, is any body help me how can i achieve to this solution?

for example

```
controller = NotificationBarController();
controller.forward();
```

source code

```
class NotificationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget contentWidget;
  final Widget barWidget;

  NotificationBar({@required this.contentWidget, @required this.barWidget});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => NotificationBarState();
}

class NotificationBarState extends State<NotificationBar>  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Offset> offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    // offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(1.0, 0.0)).animate(controller); from right
    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, -1.0)).animate(controller);
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my tired class to implementing that, but this is wrong

```
class NotificationBarController  extends ChangeNotifier {
  NotificationBarController({@required TickerProvider vsync}): _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: vsync);

  Animation<double> get animation => _animationController?.view ?? kAlwaysCompleteAnimation;

  Animation<double> get state => _animationController?.view ?? kAlwaysCompleteAnimation;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use GlobalKey for it.
First you need to instantiate and store it like this
`final key = GlobalKey<NotificationBarState>()`, then you need to pass it to `NotificationBar` constructor calling `super` with the key. Then you can access the state and its members by calling `key.currentState.someMethod()`.

However the whole idea doesn't look like *Flutter way* for me. I would suggest to subscribe to some stream or changeNotifier inside NotificationBarState and fire animation as a reaction on new event or notification

Comment: I need to have implemented code to know how can do that

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/mponkin/trigger_animation_example/tree/master/lib)

Comment: Thanks, i think this is not what i want to have. please see this library as animation controller on separated class https://github.com/mcrovero/rubber

Comment: This is going quite far from original question

Comment: I'm so sorry about this mistake